# How to set middleware in loopback js?

Tags: loopbackjs

I need to set data in session just after authentication/login so i have set middleware like this.

middleware.json

```
{  
      "initial": { },
      "session": {
        "express-session": {
          "params": {
          "secret": "mysceret",
          "saveUninitialized": true,
          "resave": true
          }
        }
      },
      "auth:before": {},
      "auth": {
        "loopback#token": {}
      },
      "auth:after": { 
        "./middleware/store-current-user": {}
      },
      "parse": { }
    }
```

in my store-current-user.js :

```
module.exports = function (options) {
       console.log(" it is working here");
    return function storeCurrentUser(req, res, next) {
         console.log(" it is not working here");
        if (!req.accessToken) {
            return next();
        }
       app.models.User.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
                }else{
                    console.log(' ok '); // it is not working.
                    req.session.user = user;
                    next();
                }
            });        
    };
};
```

Express-session :   "express-session": "^1.15.6". 
Loopback version :  "loopback": "^3.0.0"

Where I am missing ? I am unable to it figure out.

Please some help.

Comment: Does the function run at all? What are the `options` you are passing in?

Comment: @JackVaughan, yes it is working and "options" currently it is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
module.exports = function () {
       console.log(" it is working here");
    return function storeCurrentUser(req, res, next) {
         console.log(" it is not working here");
        if (!req.accessToken) {
            next();
        }
       app.models.User.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                   next(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
                }else{
                    console.log(' ok '); // it is not working.
                    req.session.user = user;
                    next();
                }
            });        
    };
};
```

- remove the `options` (add it back later if you need it)
- don't call `return next()`, just `next()` alone
- also, are you defining app somewhere?

Comment: "app" defined separated, I have noticed that it is working when switching in other routes in my app such as "user_profile", so loopback phases having some issue or i am missing some step. since it is not executing just after "auth:after middleware".

Comment: No error is thrown? When I've referenced app within a function like this, I've passed in app to the function so that it knows about it.